# Can I refer to properties directly in entity constructor with EclipseLink?

Tags: eclipselink

EclipseLink version is 2.5.1

We've moved from GlassFish web-server to TomCat. This made us switch to static weaving because with TomCat dynamic weaving doesn't really work that easy.
Now that static weaving works, it seems to work quite a bit differently.
If I have an entity which sets some property directly in the constructor:

```
class Entity {
    @Column
    private String name;

    public Entity() {
        name = "something";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Long story short this test will fail:

```
Entity e = new Entity();
assertEquals("something", e.getName()); // e.getName() returns null
```

This happens because `getName()`, after weaving, is not returning `this.name` anymore. Instead it calls a routing for initialization (if it's needed) and (I guess) gets the value of the property from some underlying HashMap.
But constructor is not being weaved, I even have looked into the sources of weaver and seems to be explicitly opting out of this:

```
/**
 * Construct a MethodWeaver and allow it to process the method.
 */
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String methodName, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, methodName, desc, signature, exceptions);
    if (!alreadyWeaved) {
        // skip constructors, they will not changed
        if (!"<init>".equals(methodName) && !"<cinit>".equals(methodName)) {
            // remaining modifications to the 'body' of the class are
            // delegated to MethodWeaver
            mv = new MethodWeaver(this, methodName, desc, mv);
        }
    }
    return mv;
}
```

The question is, maybe I miss something here? Is it the actual reality with EclipseLink 2.5.1 that you can't use properties directly in entity's own ctor? (and it's not even mentioned anywhere, not googlable at least)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out yes, we can.

But there was a problem that led us to the property being not visible to the getter.
We actually have MappedSuperclass inheritance here and we were shadowing this field in the child class. Essentially this:

```
class A {
    @Column()
    protected String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Column()
    protected String name;

    // no @Override here
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

So we were just shadowing the property.